# SQL Server, Group By AND get first result After a Static Status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have one problem, and I can't solve it. I have a events datas In the MSSQL Server table. The Events appear every time, when something change on the Job. So, one record Include EventId, [JobId] its show which is the job, where something happened, and the time, [TimeStamp], when happened it, and the [Status].

I want group by [JobId], and get the first record (by [TimeStamp]) after one status, So if the [Status] = 'Finalized'. So in the DB we have more 'finalized' record with same [JobId], but I want get the first [TimeStamp].

Here, you can see, that its appears multiple time, with same [JobId], but I want get only the firts by [TimeStamp].

[image: Table content]

Here is my query.

[image: my query]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to get the first result only (which most likely will be the one with the lowest `EventId` too), give this a try:

```
SELECT MIN(EventId) AS EventId, Status, JobId, MIN(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp
    FROM [Event] WHERE Status = 'Finalized' 
    GROUP BY Status, JobId
    ORDER BY JobId desc, TimeStamp
```

Not sure if there's anything else that you need, but if you do just let me know and I can adjust the query around your requirements :)

Comment: Ohh, It's already good, but (its my mistake) I didn't told, that not the 'Finalized' status the only one which is good, it has 4 different status, so (if status = 'Finalized' OR status = 'Client Finalized' ...), and now, if I modify your query, with other 3 status, its give me the other 3 status also, but its doesn't matter, which is the status, only important that the status must be on of from 4 and it should be appear only once in the result, by timestamp first (most older).

Comment: I SOLVE IT. Just leave the status from the query works. Thank YOU very much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by eventid, jobid order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```